# What is CustomControl can, but UserControl cannot in code implementation level?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, custom-controls

I have read some of the blog and documentation which are discussing about the purpose of `CustomControl` and `UserControl` in WPF, but I am still kind of confusing about the implementation as below:

- I think this should be called `UserControl` style, here I inherit from an existing control class, not `UserControl` or `Control`

```xml
    <ToggleButton x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                    ... some template code
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>
```

```cs
    public partial class MyButton : ToggleButton
    {
        public MyButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

- I think this should be called `CustomControl` Style

```xml
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButton }">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    ... control template code
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

```cs
    public class MyButton : ToggleButton
    {
        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton )));
        }
    }
```

Here I implement the `MyBtton` class in both way, and I test the code, they should be working the same like each other.

1. In `UserControl` style, I can setup the `template` property for root item, which is ToggleButton here. And I think this is the same as `CustomControl` style, which is given the theme with `Style` in resource directionary.
2. In `UserControl`style, I can also add the static constructor and override meta data, which make `UserControl` support the theme like `CustomControl` ( if this is indeed true ).
3. In `UserControl` style, I can see the final UI from designer and the Visual Studio also "binding" the CS and relative XAML together, which is kind of convenient.

So, why we still need `CustomControl`? Anything that `UserControl` cannot, but only `CustomControl` can?

Comment: Dude, I have no idea what you mean, but a "UserControl" by definition is any class that derives from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`. which is not the case here. Therefore it could be said that your examples here are both custom controls.

Comment: Really? You mean my both examples are Custom Control? The only difference between them is the different base class, but not the implementation? If so, this answer is really out of my expectation.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617852.aspx  Really that is the definition.

Comment: @winterTTr I think [this](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html) is a good explanation of the difference.

Comment: @Blam So, that means, the word UserControl and CustomControl is the different concept, not specific to implementation.